# infowindow google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Как добавить infowindow, по клику на маркеры?

```
var markers = [];
var infowindow = [];
var col = array_coordinates.length;
for (var i = 0; i <= col; i++) {
    var ll = array_coordinates[i].split(',');
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(ll[0], ll[1]);
        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:latlng,
        map: map,
        title: array_coordinates[i],
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        visible: true
        //icon: 'images/beachflag.png'
    });
    infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
        content: "ghbdftn"
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
        infowindow[i].open(map, markers[i]);

    });  
}
```

Есть карта, на карте есть маркеры, которые добавляются из массива, так вот я хочу, чтобы при клике по маркеру вверху над маркером появлялось окно, оно же infowindow. Вопрос: как реализовать?

Comment: Столкнулся с такой-же проблемой: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/696908/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-google-map-3-0/696921#696921

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var markers = [];
var infowindow = [];
var col = array_coordinates.length;
for (var i = 0; i <= col; i++) {
    infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
        content: array_marker_info[i]
    });
    var ll = array_coordinates[i].split(',');
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(ll[0], ll[1]);
        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:latlng,
        map: map,
        title: array_coordinates[i],
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        visible: true,
        icon: 'images/beachflag.png'
    });
    setInfoWindowHandlers(i);
}

function setInfoWindowHandlers(i) {
    markers[i].addListener('click', function() {
        console.log(i);
        infowindow[i].open(map, markers[i]);
    });
}
```