# Информационные окна google map 3.0

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Проблема следующая:
Не привязываются окна к маркерам, привязывается только к одному.

```
var marker = [], 
    win = [];
for (var key in jsons) {
   //  .....
   marker[key] = new window.google.maps.Marker({
       map: map,
       position: position
   }); //тут добавления маркеров

   win[key] = new window.google.maps.InfoWindow({
       content: key
   });  добавление окон

   window.google.maps.event.addListener(marker[key], 'click', function () {
       win[key].open(map, marker[key]);
   });
}
```

Постоянно открывает первый маркер (даже когда нажимаем на 2 маркер, все равно открывается первый), в чем может быть проблема?

Когда вывожу после цикла

```
console.log(marker);
```

Показывает оба маркера с разной информацией, также при выводе `win` - также 2 разных окна, но открывается почему - то, всегда первый. В чем проблема не понимаю. Как только уже не пробовал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо, разобрался. Нужно было сделать так:

```
info[marker.position] = ...
marker.addListener('click', function () {
    infowindow.setContent(info[this.position]);
    infowindow.open(chart, this);
});
```